# Unable to join arbiter to a replica set

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a arbiter to replica set.
Unable to join arbiter to a replica set.

port is listening -

```
netstat -an | grep PORT
tcp6       0      0 :::PORT                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Able to connect locally using shell however unable to connect from any other servers. below is the log.

```
2021-11-26T06:47:01.358+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1637909221:358715][1:0x7f9499561a40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2021-11-26T06:47:01.375+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2021-11-26T06:47:01.411+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/mongodb/DBpath/diagnostic.data'
2021-11-26T06:47:01.412+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local voted for document at startup.
2021-11-26T06:47:01.413+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Rollback ID is 1
2021-11-26T06:47:01.413+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset
2021-11-26T06:47:01.413+0000 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured
2021-11-26T06:47:01.414+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port PORT ssl
2021-11-26T06:52:01.413+0000 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured
2021-11-26T06:57:01.413+0000 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured
```

After adding addArb("node:PORT")
I see following for the node in rs.status output from primary -

```
"stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
"lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PORT as a TCP-port!
Port is always some integer value between 1 to 65536.

Put your arbiter f.ex. to port 30000

Comment: port is not a problem I've used 4 digit number. I can connect to arbiter from within the instance however is not connecting from any other devices.

Comment: Can you add (in the ticket) your arbiters config file. Do that arbiter listen right network interface. Is there some firewall between node and outside word...

Comment: for security reasons I can't post the conf file. I can tell you I'm specifying replica set to be part of it. however I get following error in the log - `I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured`

Comment: "Replication has not yet been configured" means that none of the other members of RS has managed to contact that node. You don't give enough information to solve this problem.  NOTE: "If specifying an IPv6 address or a hostname that resolves to an IPv6 address to net.bindIp, you must start mongos or mongod with net.ipv6 : true to enable IPv6 support. Specifying an IPv6 address to net.bindIp does not enable IPv6 support."